# How to change configurable product main image by associated product image based on color attributes?

Tags: magento

I am using magento (1.8.1.0) configurable product with size and color attributes. I want to change the main-image on configurable-product view as per the options chosen Like If I choose red-color then image of associated-product which has red color attribute value should display on main-image as soon as I choose the option.

How can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Simple Configurable Products extension for this.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

This extension is not updated for latest version, so you need to do some changes that you can read from the extension reviews.